# React-Calendar, How to disable dates only in one month?

Tags: next.js, react-calendar

I would like to disable selected dates in calendar. I dit it, but problem is when I disable date in month may, it will disable it in all months. For example:
If I disable day 4th in May it will disable day 4th in all months.
I saw also this link: [how to disable some dates in react-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641423/how-to-disable-some-dates-in-react-calendar)
How can I fix this. Thanks

```
let disableDates = ''
  let date1 = ''

  let selectedDays = []
  let disable = []
  
  const handleClick = (date) => {

     disableDates = new Date(date)
     date1=disableDates.getDate()
     
     disable.push(date1)
     console.log(disable)  //(2) [2, 3]

     selectedDays.push(date)
    console.log('selectedDays', selectedDays)  //(2) [Fri Jun 02..., Sat Jun...]

  }
```

ReactCalendar here:

```
<ReactCalendar 
      minDate={new Date()}
     // tileDisabled={({date}) => date.getDate()===date1}
      tileDisabled={({date}) => disable.includes(date.getDate()) }
      onClickDay={handleClick} 
       
       />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using the same `disable` array to store the disabled dates for all months. To solve, try to separate `disable` array for each month:

```
let disabledDates = {};

const handleClick = (date) => {
  const selectedDate = new Date(date);
  const month = selectedDate.getMonth();

  const disabledMonthDates = disabledDates[month] || [];
  const selectedDay = selectedDate.getDate();

  if (!disabledMonthDates.includes(selectedDay)) {
    disabledMonthDates.push(selectedDay);
  } else {
    const index = disabledMonthDates.indexOf(selectedDay);
    disabledMonthDates.splice(index, 1);
  }
  disabledDates[month] = disabledMonthDates;
  console.log(disabledDates);
};
```

- ReactCalendar:

  ```
  <ReactCalendar
  minDate={new Date()}
  tileDisabled={({ date }) =>
    disabledDates[date.getMonth()]?.includes(date.getDate())
  }
  onClickDay={handleClick}
  />
  ```